# How to retrieve client IP within a Docker container running Apache on AWS Elastic Container Service?

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a Docker server running Apache 2.4.25 (Debian) PHP 7.3.5.
This container is "hosted" within an Amazon Elastic Container Service.
The default AWS EC2s are sat behind an AWS application load balancer.

**I want to be able to obtain, in PHP, the users/clients IP address.**

My presumption based on my limited knowledge is that this IP address will need to be handed from the ALB, to the EC2, then to the Docker container, and finally for Apache to pick up.

I have tried to shorten the stack by attempting to obtain the IP within a Docker container running on my local machine, however still I wasn't able to find a way for Docker to fetch and pass through my IP to Apache.

I know typically you'd have the X-Forwarded header from the ALB, but I have not been able to work out how Docker can take this and pass it through to Apache.

I expected to have the client IP in `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` or `$_SERVER['X_FORWARDED']`.

Within the AWS hosted Docker containers
`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` contains an IP within the VPC subnet
`$_SERVER['X_FORWARDED']` does not exist

Comment: you can use `X-Forwarded-For: client-ip-address` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/x-forwarded-headers.html

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-capture-client-ip-addresses/

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't "just work" with an Application Load Balancer and EC2s running Docker images